# Excluding previous values from database using PHP and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, random, mysqli

So let's say I have 30 entries in my database, I select the first 7 to get on my first page like this:

```
$qryRandomGallery = "SELECT a.Titel, a.KW, a.KWKidsID, a.KWKidsBeschrijving, b.ScoreAfbeelding, c.GebruikersNaam
                        FROM tblKWKids AS A
                        LEFT JOIN tblScore AS b
                        ON a.ScoreID = b.ScoreID
                        LEFT JOIN tblUser as C
                        ON a.UserID = c.UserID
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 6";
if ($stmtRandomGallery = mysqli_prepare($dbconn, $qryRandomGallery)) {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtRandomGallery);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmtRandomGallery, $KWTitel, $KWURL, $KWID, $KWKiddyBeschrijving, $ScoreAfb, $USER);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmtRandomGallery);
}

$qryRandomGalleryBIG = "SELECT a.Titel, a.KW, a.KWKidsID, a.KWKidsBeschrijving, b.ScoreAfbeelding, c.GebruikersNaam
                        FROM tblKWKids AS A
                        LEFT JOIN tblScore AS b
                        ON a.ScoreID = b.ScoreID
                        LEFT JOIN tblUser as C
                        ON a.UserID = c.UserID
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 1";
if ($stmtRandomGalleryBIG = mysqli_prepare($dbconn, $qryRandomGalleryBIG)) {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtRandomGalleryBIG);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmtRandomGalleryBIG, $KWTitelB, $KWURLB, $KWIDB, $KWKiddyBeschrijvingB, $ScoreAfbB, $USERB);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmtRandomGalleryBIG);
}
```

and then this as my php

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmtRandomGallery)){
$content .= '<div>';
$content .= '<a href="galerij.php?id=' . $KWID . '">';
$content .= '<img src="' . $KWURL . '" title="' . $KWTitel . '" alt="' . $KWTitel . '" class="image">';
$content .= '<h5>' . $KWTitel . ' door: ' . $USER . '</h5>';
$content .= '<p>' . $KWKiddyBeschrijving . '</p>';
$content .= '<img src="' . $ScoreAfb . '" title="Score" alt="Score" class="img">';
$content .= '</a>';
$content .= '</div>';
}
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmtRandomGalleryBIG)){
$content .= '<h2>Uitgelicht werk van ' . $USERB . '</h2>';
$content .= '<a href="galerij.php?id=' . $KWIDB . '">';
$content .= '<img src="' . $KWURLB . '" title="' . $KWTitelB . '" alt="' . $KWTitelB . '" id="image">';
$content .= '<h3>' . $KWTitelB . ' door: ' . $USERB . '</h3>';
$content .= '<h4>' . $KWKiddyBeschrijvingB . '</h4>';
$content .= '<img src="' . $ScoreAfbB . '" title="Score" alt="Score" id="score">';
$content .= '</a>';
}
```

Now, how do I exclude the results from the first stmt to select another random image for my BIG image?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Take the IDs of your first query and stuff them into the second query as a `not in`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE idField NOT IN (x,y,z,p,q,r)
```

This'll exclude them from second query's results.

Comment: So for example I'll use this code;

    'FROM tbKWKids
    WHERE KWKidsID NOT IN (' . $stmtRandomGallery . ',' . $stmtRandomGalleryBIG . ')'